# .htaccess rewrite rule with existing directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` file on my website root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?t=$1 [L]
```

It means that, for some links like

```
www.website.com/foo
www.website.com/bar
```

it will be internally replaced by

```
www.website.com/index.php?t=foo
www.website.com/index.php?t=bar
```

Problem is: one of this directories (say, `bar`) exists, and I want to be able to use the link `www.website.com/bar/file.pdf`, so I had to modify `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?t=$1 [L]
```

I removed the line ending in `!-d`, which means “if the directory doesn’t exist”. But now I see

```
www.website.com/bar/index.php?t=bar
```

So how can I have both

```
www.website.com/bar
www.website.com/bar/file.pdf
```

with the first redirecting (internally) to `www.website.com/index.php?t=bar` and the second pointing to the right file?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if /bar/index.php exists:

```
RewriteEngine On

#
# rule 1
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php [QSA,L]

#
# rule 2
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?t=$1 [L]
```

This way if directory /bar/ exists, it's rewritten definitively by the first rule 1 to /bar/index.php. At the same time, /bar/file.pdf will not be touched as the file exists.

Comment: Actually, /bar/ exists, but it should rewrite to /?t=bar. There's no index.php inside it, the only file I want to share the link is a PDF.

Comment: Well, I gave up. Moved the PDF to the root directory, and now I have a simpler .htaccess and no bugs. Thanks for trying!